# django polymorphic model, filter on subclass field

Tags: django, model, polymorphism

I have some models using django-polymorphic-model

eg.

```
class Article(PolymorphicModel):
  ...
class Blog(Article):
  tags = ...
class Story(Article):
  publish = ...
```

Normally if I get all articles, I just do `Article.objects.all()`, however what if I want to get all articles that tags are empty? If I do `Articles.objects.filter(tags__isnull=True)` it will break because other models don't have this field, I would like to include Story entries too, do I really have to split into 2 different queries and combine again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK After some digging for the [documentation](https://github.com/chrisglass/django_polymorphic/issues/8) through issues, here is how to do it

```
Articles.objects.filter(Blog___tags__isnull=True)
```

Comment: What if you have multiple subclasses with the same field, is there a way to filter across all subclasses with tags__isnull=True?

Comment: I don't have the code with me now, but I think if all subclasses have the field, it should work, even better, if all subclasses have same field, that field should sit on the parent class, so it definitely works.

Answer (score 2):

Hope you found an answer before.

```
Articles.objects.filter(Q(Blog___tags__isnull=True)|Q(Story__tags__isnull=True))
```